# Sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria many files in one line?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonaQube 9.1. Community Edition

```
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1,e2,e3
 
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=java:S115
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=**/*Type.java
 
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey=java:S115
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey=**/*Enum.java

 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e3.ruleKey=java:S115
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e3.resourceKey=**/NEStatus.java
```

Nice. This work fine.

But to much lines.

Is it possible smt like this?

```
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1
     
 sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=java:S115
   sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=**/*Type.java,**/*Enum.java,**/NEStatus.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise EditionVersion 8.9.6
The comma-separated path names didn't work. I had to proceed with individual ruleKey and resourceKeys for the same rule exclusion.